# Vertical scroll difficulty with webview in PageView ( flutter )

Tags: flutter, webview

I have add a WebView page on my PageView but some users tel me have trouble to scroll vertically. I tested on my samsung galaxy s7 I have no problem. But with my iphone I faced this difficulty. When it happen, user need to be perfecly vertical and continue to scoll, if it vertical but after little bit shiffted the vertical scroll is loose, and if the shiffted is too big it scroll horizontally because of PageView.

I have no problem when I use listview. How to improve webview scroll ?

I see this video who refer this problem
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RA-vLF_vnng

So I follow this recommandation

```
   WebView(
            initialUrl: 'my url',
            gestureRecognizers: Set()
            ..add(Factory<VerticalDragGestureRecognizer>(
                () => VerticalDragGestureRecognizer())),
          ),
```

But no change ...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I've understand correctly, you simply need to remove the gesture recognizer. (Pageview scroll is horizontal so shouldn't affect page view vertical scroll.)

You can watch the moment of the video you referenced where this is mentioned: https://youtu.be/RA-vLF_vnng?t=222

Comment: With or without gesture recognizer I have always this issue :(